# Remove library project from apk using gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a library project used by my project. Also my project has several build flavors. In code I reference some classes from that library. I need that library to be removed from my .apk for some of the flavors. I know that this will lead to `NoClassDefFoundError` but it's ok for me.

I tried to use `flavorCompile`task instead of compile but this were leading to errors during compilation of my project (as expected). So how can I make that libeaey project present during compilation but removed from .apk?

P.S. I know that I can remove it during compilation AND alter some of the code files which are using the classes from that library but for me `NoClassDefFoundError` is ok so I'd like to not have different versions of the same .java files per flavor.

**EDIT1**
I've found [this](http://ashishb.net/tech/android-gradle-and-compile-time-dependencies/) article but Gradle version seems to be older then current one. Also now I know that I'm looking fot ability to add compile time dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

you could add flavour specific compile block in dependencies, so ex. if you have flavour free and pay
use

```
dependencies {

    payCompile '<something>'
}
```

Comment: Like I said I tried it. But it excludes it in compile time which leads to build impossible to finish.

Comment: and have you try **configuration** options listed in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html in **Example 52.18. Dependency configurations for project**

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't understand this example.

Comment: I must make configuration for your flavours and add 'configuration' field to compile line of your library

Answer (score 0):

you might use provided:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'optional-lib'
}
```